# How can I ignore a file in volume?

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, git-submodules

I use git submodules to make it easier to create a docker-compose file to work on my laptop.

I mount each submodule via volume.

As a result, each service is present at the top level .git file with a link to the parent repository.

One of the projects uses a private package distributed via npm. When trying to download the yarn package, it crashes with an error because it uses git and git cannot find the parent repository.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a file `.dockerignore` a put `.git` inside it.

Comment: This did not work, seems docker-compose did not use .dockerignore file. Or am I doing something wrong. 
i try to add to parent repository with **/.git pattern and try to add to each submodule with .git pattern

Comment: should i rebuild images?

Comment: Yes. I use it with docker compose too.